# Can anyone give some pointers about what is wrong with this proof?

Tags: real-analysis

Given a function $g$ defined on the real line satisfying these conditions:

1. $g'(0) = k$
2. $g(0) \neq 0$
3. $g(x + y) = g(x)g(y)$ for all $x, y$

Show that $g(0) = 1$ and $g'(x) = kg(x)$ for all x.

My "proof" is as follows:

Define $f(x) = g(x)g(x)$, then $f'(x) = g'(x)g(x) + g(x)g'(x) = 2g'(x)g(x)$

$\implies f'(0) = 2g'(0)g(0) = 2kg(0)$ (from definition 1)

But $f(x) = g(2x)$ (definition 3) so $f'(0)=2g(0)=2k$

$\implies f'(0) = 2kg(0) = 2k \implies g(0) = 1$

For the second part:

$\frac{d}{dx}g(x+y) = g'(x+y) = g'(x)g(y)$ (from definition 3)

$\implies g'(x+y) = g'(x)g(y)$

$\implies g'(0 + y) = g'(0)g(y)$

$\implies g'(y) = kg(y)$ (from definition 1)

Any pointers on where the flaw in the argument is? I'm new to proofs and would appreciate any help!

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! For me, the only problem is that you don't have in your hypotheses that $k\ne 0$, nor that $gˆ$ is differentiable everywhere.

Comment: I see! Perhaps this method is not the way to go, I don't think I can modify it without changing a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The fact that $g(0) = 1$ can be demonstrated in a less circuitous fashion.  Observe directly that property 3 implies for $x = y = 0$ $$g(0) = g(0 + 0) = g(0)g(0) = g(0)^2.$$  Consequently, $$0 = g(0)^2 - g(0) = g(0) (g(0) - 1),$$ and since property 2 excludes $g(0) = 0$, we are forced to conclude $g(0) = 1$.  Note this result does not rely on differentiability.

Comment: Very clever! It was the reliance on differentiability that sunk me